# d3 v4: Clip path not updating after pan and zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a rect holding a clip path, which I'm applying to a group (holding a tree). I have a zoom function bound to the rect which transforms the group, which works fine. I've applied the clip path to the group, and when it first renders it looks like it should. However, after panning or zooming, the drawn tree extends beyond the bounds of the clip path while maintaining its previously-clipped appearance.

```
var svg = d3.select(this.$.chart);
var svg2 = svg.select("svg");
var main = svg2.append("g")
    .attr("class","main")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var treeContainer = svg2.append('g')
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")")
var treeBaseRect = treeContainer.append("rect") // the rectangle which holds the clip path and zoom actions for the tree.
    .attr("width", width + margin2.right)
    .attr("height", height2)
    .style("fill", "#eee")
    .style("pointer-events", "all")
    .call(d3.zoom().scaleExtent([0.1, 3]).on("zoom", function () {
        svgGroup.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
    }));
treeContainer.append('defs').append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width + margin2.right)
    .attr("height", height2);
var svgGroup = treeContainer.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path","url(#clip)");
```

Here's some screenshots. First one shows the initial render, which is fine (the clip area is the darker grey rectangle):

[image]

Then after doing a scroll zoom or pan, note how the tree is still 'originally' clipped, and not being clipped properly outside of the gray area:
[image]

And this is my clip path rect in the DOM structure:
[image]

You can tell that the clip rect is still where it's meant to be, but the tree is completely ignoring it. No idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I hadn't added enough groups. The easy solution was to add another `append("g")` to the svgGroup I was creating, for a last line looking like this:

```
var svgGroup = treeContainer.append("g")
                .attr("clip-path","url(#clip)")
                .append("g");
```

Comment: This helped solve my issue as well. Do you know why this is? Why do you have to have another 'g' inside your clipped 'g'?

Comment: This fixed the issue for me too. I had a tooltip path which was not clipping. I simply added an additional group in between the clip-path and the tooltip group.Just this:
`svg.append("g").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)").append("g")`